# Why is this update query so slow and how can I improve it

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set av.UnitType to the values in ut.unittype, as long as three columns match, and I am wondering what parts are of this statement are causing it to take so long:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE `db`.`table_av` av, `db`.`table_ut` ut 
SET av.UnitType = ut.unittype
WHERE TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM av.id) = ut.id
AND av.veh = ut.veh
AND av.date LIKE CONCAT('%', ut.Year);
```

Comment: On the list of things that can make queries slow, some of the worst are "using functions, or doing calculations, on field values in comparisons"...functions like `TRIM()` and `CONCAT()`; also on the list are "LIKE conditions with leading wildcards".... like '%yearvalue'. ....and stylistically, using "comma-join" notation has been obsolete AND out of favor for literally decades.

Comment: Change it to a `SELECT` query that finds the related rows, and then use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan. Adding indexes on the `veh` column in both tables might help.

Comment: What is the schema of the two tables? Why does one ID have leading zeros and the related one does not?

Comment: The last comparison might be better as `YEAR(av.date) = ut.Year`, although it still uses a function so it's not optimal. But it's a simpler function than formatting the date and then doing a wildcard match.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I imported ut from a csv file that someone gave me, they are both in the same schema.

Comment: @Barmar av.date is a text field rather than a date field.

Comment: That's another problem. Use proper datatypes.

Comment: @Barmar true, but I don't have authority over that so I was hoping for a decent work around

Comment: If you have control over what you uploaded, make the important relating fields compatible during or just after the import. As @Uueerdo points out, calculations in your where clause will slow things down a lot.

Comment: If you can't change the schemas, you're probably out of luck. Most techniques for optimizing queries involve adding indexes.

Comment: @SloanThrasher thanks, I'm going to run with that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the join to currently used syntax

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

UPDATE `db`.`table_av` av, 
    JOIN `db`.`table_ut` ut 
        ON TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM av.id) = ut.id
            AND av.veh = ut.veh
            AND av.date LIKE CONCAT('%', ut.Year);
    SET av.UnitType = ut.unittype
```

That last line should use the date functions instead of like (if possible). Better yet, make sure the two columns are 
compatible types in each table (ie TIMESTAMP, or at least 4 digit years in an int or varchar.

Comment: Thank you, I got an error because the set is above the join, but it is working when I switched their positions.

Comment: Like the change I made to the answer?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this has any effect on performance. I think MySQL simply translates from one syntax to the other.

Comment: This answer isn't about performance, there are other comments regarding that, and the fixes for the performance issues are beyond the scope of the code shown.